# How to recover after Ubuntu freeze on boot after installing broadcom STA driver

Tags: 12.04, wireless, boot, drivers, broadcom

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 on bootcamp of my early 2011 macbook pro using the ubuntu windows installer. The wifi did not work and follow this instruction (although for Quantal) to fix it

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2/Quantal

That did not fix the problem and I then relized the additional hardware is suggesting the broadcom STA driver so I updated and restarted it to work and now my screen freeze on boot. It just goes all purple and sits there.

For me that I realized what Grub is in the last 30 min, I do not know how to fix this. The recovery mode load busybox and don't know what to do with it.

How can I remove that driver without the live cd thing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and was able to remove it by typing "sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source"(remove the quotes)

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this via busybox.

Comment: Were you able to boot? If not, how did you run that command then?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off your wireless with physical switch or BIOS (or EFI in Mac)
Then load Ubuntu, remove proprietary driver with **sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source**...

if you cant turn off your Wifi card via hardware switch try 'console' or 'recovery' modes in GRUB.

To enter these menu, press and hold Left Shift key in keyboard. Then select a option or edit with 'e' key in keyboard (selected option) F10 or Ctrl+x (or cmd+x) to boot it...